# Setting up nginx and php-fpm on CentOS 7 - which config file do I alter? I'm so lost

Tags: nginx, php, vps, php-fpm, fastcgi

I'm intermediate with Ubuntu and Apache, but a total noob to CentOS.  I want to setup a 1 CPU 1 GB RAM test VPS for a phpbb 3.1 forum, and I'm following this tutorial: [How To Install Linux, Nginx, MySQL, PHP (LEMP) stack On CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7)

Most of it is vanilla setup, but I started saying WTF when I got to this part of the tut: [Step Four — Configure Nginx to Process PHP Pages](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7#step-four-%E2%80%94-configure-nginx-to-process-php-pages)

Running `sudo vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` returns an empty file (doesn't exist), but whatever, I'll just keep pluggin along... That was until they started talking about uncommenting lines (that don't exists).

The nginx documentation isn't much help either as it kicks things off talking about keeping for FCGI settings in `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` then proceeds to explain nothing about it's contents beyond showing an example file.

So my question is: What file should I setup my server in?  Will that one work?  Anyone have a better tutorial/guide?  phpBB does provide a standard [config file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phpbb/phpbb3/master/phpBB/docs/nginx.sample.conf) (not that I'd know what to do or where to put it), but it's for nginx 0.8.35 - which seems a little behind the 1.6.3 I'm now running.

I want to see how much I performance I can squeeze out of a minimal VPS running a board with anywhere from 300,000 - 2 mil requests per month.  So I'm all ears for additional pointers.

A question: should I just consider an installer script like VPSSIM?  I was concerned with the potential overhead (and that I really don't know what everything is on there and what I'll need).

I'm lost guys, I appreciate any help.

EDIT: The `# ls` on /etc/nginx:

```
conf.d                fastcgi_params          mime.types          scgi_params           win-utf
default.d             fastcgi_params.default  mime.types.default  scgi_params.default
fastcgi.conf          koi-utf                 nginx.conf          uwsgi_params
fastcgi.conf.default  koi-win                 nginx.conf.default  uwsgi_params.default
```

`conf.d` and `default.d` are both empty.

Comment: You skipped a step or two. Go back to the beginning and try again.

Comment: Which one or two specifically?  php, mysql, and nginx are all installed, and the first two are configured properly (at least up to that point in the guide).  There's a /etc/nginx/conf.d/ directory, there just wasn't a file in it.  I'll edit my post with the contents of the /etc/nginx/ dir if it'd help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the problem today and after searching I eventually figured it out.

1. Go to your Domain, i.e. open in a web browser:

   ```
   http://server_domain_name_or_IP/
   ```

   On that page NGINX will list

[image: Nginx_start_page]

2. EDIT the File listed there
   In my case it is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.